# How to implement Hasicorp vault 3 node cluster?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

We have implemented hasicorp open source vault as single node with consul backend.
We need help regarding implementing vault 3 node cluster for HA in single datacenter and also well as in multidatacenter.
Could you please help me on this.

Answer (score 4):

The Vault Deployment guide has more on this.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/operations/ops-deployment-guide#help-and-reference

Combine it with this guide: https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/operations/ops-vault-ha-consul

I shall assume, just based on the fact that you've already gotten a single node up with a Consul backend, that you already know a little about scripting, Git, configuring new SSH connections, installing software, and Virtual Machines.

Also, these are hard to explain, and have much better resources elsewhere.

Further if you get stuck with the prerequisites, tools to install, or downloading the code, please have a look at the resources on the internet.

If you get an error with Vault working improperly, though, make a Github issue ASAP.

Anyway, with that out of the way, the short answer is this:

**Step 1: Set up 3 Consul servers, each with references to each other.**

**Step 2: Set up 3 Vault servers, each of them independent, but with a reference to a Consul 
address as their Storage Backend.**

**Step 3: Initialize the Cluster with your brand new Vault API.**

Now for the long answer.

## Prerequisites

## OS-Specific Prerequisites

- MacOS: OSX 10.13 or later
- Windows: Windows must have [Powershell 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32385347/2146138) or later. If you're on Windows 7, I recommend Windows Management Framework 4.0, because it's easier to install

## Vagrant

Set up Vagrant, because it will take care of all of the networking and resource setup for the underlying infrastructure to use, here.

Especially for Vagrant, the Getting Started guide takes about 30 minutes once you have Vagrant and Virtualbox installed: https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/getting-started/index.html

#### Install Tools

1. Make sure you have [Git](https://git-scm.com/downloads) installed
2. Install the *latest* version of Vagrant  ([NOTE: WINDOWS 7 AND WINDOWS 8 REQUIRE POWERSHELL >= 3](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/06/02/weekend-scripter-install-powershell-3-0-on-windows-7/))
3. Install the *latest* version of VMWare or [Virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)

#### Download the Code for this demonstration

*Related Vendor Documentation Link: [https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository](https://help.github.com/articles/cloning-a-repository_)*

`git clone https://github.com/v6/super-duper-vault-train.git`

#### Use this Code to Make a Vault Cluster

*Related Vagrant Vendor Documentation Link: [https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/index.html#why-vagrant-](https://www.vagrantup.com/intro/index.html#why-vagrant-_)*

`cd super-duper-vault-train`
`vagrant up`  ##  NOTE: You may have to wait a while for this, and there will be some "connection retry" errors for a long time before a successful connection occurs, because the VM is booting.  Make sure you have the latest version, and try the Vagrant getting started guide, too
`vagrant status`
`vagrant ssh instance5`
After you do this, you'll see your command prompt change to show `vagrant@instance5`.
You can also `vagrant ssh` to other VMs listed in the output of `vagrant status`.

You can now use Vault or Consul from within the VM for which you ran `vagrant ssh`.

## Vault

#### Explore the Vault Cluster

`ps -ef | grep vault`  ##  Check the Vault process (run while inside a Vagrant-managed Instance)
`ps -ef | grep consul`  ##  Check the Consul process (run while inside a Vagrant-managed Instance)
`vault version`  ##  Output should be `Vault v0.10.2 ('3ee0802ed08cb7f4046c2151ec4671a076b76166')`
`consul version`  ##  Output should show Consul Agent version and Raft Protocol version

The Vagrant boxes have the following IP addresses:

```
192.168.13.35

192.168.13.36

192.168.13.37
```

Vault is on port 8200.

Consul is on port 8500.

#### Click the Links

http://192.168.13.35:8200 (Vault)

http://192.168.13.35:8500 (Consul)

http://192.168.13.36:8200 (Vault)

http://192.168.13.36:8500 (Consul)

http://192.168.13.37:8200 (Vault)

http://192.168.13.37:8500 (Consul)

#### Start Vault Data

*Related Vendor Documentation Link: [https://www.vaultproject.io/api/system/init.html](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/system/init.html_)*

Start Vault.
Run this command on one of the Vagrant-managed VMs, or somewhere on your computer that has `curl` installed.

```
    curl -s --request PUT -d '{"secret_shares": 3,"secret_threshold": 2}' http://192.168.13.35:8200/v1/sys/init
```

#### Unseal Vault

*Related Vendor Documentation Link: [https://www.vaultproject.io/api/system/unseal.html](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/system/unseal.html_)*

This will unseal the Vault at `192.168.13.35:8200`.  You can use the same process for `192.168.13.36:8200` and `192.168.13.37:8200`.

1. Use your unseal key to replace the value for key `abcd1430890...`, and run this on the Vagrant-managed VM.

```
    curl --request PUT --data '{"key":"abcd12345678..."}' http://192.168.13.35:8200/v1/sys/unseal
```

2. Run that `curl` command again. But use a different value for `"key":`. Replace `efgh2541901...` with a different key than you used in the previous step, from the keys you received when running the `v1/sys/init` endpoint.

```
    curl --request PUT --data '{"key":"efgh910111213..."}' http://192.168.13.35:8200/v1/sys/unseal
```

## Non-Vagrant

Please refer to the file PRODUCTION_INSTALLATION.md in this repository.

## Codified Vault Policies and Configuration

To Provision Vault via its API, please refer to the 
`provision_vault` folder.

It has data and scripts.

The `data` folder's tree corresponds to the HashiCorp Vault API
endpoints, similar to the following:

https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/codifying-vault-policies-and-configuration#layout-and-design

You can use the Codified Vault 
Policies and Configuration 
with your initial Root token, after
initializing and unsealing Vault, 
to configure Vault quickly via its API.

The .json files inside each folder
correspond to the payloads to send to Vault
via its API, but there may also be `.hcl`,
`.sample`, and `.sh` files for convenience's sake.

Answer (score 2):

Hashicorp have written some guidance on how to get started with setting up a HA Vault and Consul configuration:

https://www.vaultproject.io/guides/operations/vault-ha-consul.html