# I am having trouble with PowerShell code that doesn't run properly in v2

Tags: xml, powershell-2.0

We are trying to update our BIOS within a task sequence and I have a script provided by Lenovo which is working fine in Windows 10 and PowerShell v5. However, it is not working properly in Windows 7 with PowerShell v2. We can't upgrade to v5 on the Windows 7 machines.

The script reads an XML file I have exported from the SCCM and matches the appropriate BIOS package, downloads it and runs it.

So the script looks like:

```cs
[xml]$Packages = Get-Content BIOSPackages.xml

# Environment variable call for task sequence only
$tsenv = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.SMS.TSEnvironment

$BIOS = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2 -Class Win32_BIOS).SMBIOSBIOSVersion.Substring(0,4)

$ns = New-Object Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $Packages.NameTable
$ns.AddNamespace("def", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04")

$Xpathqry = "/def:Objs/def:Obj//def:MS[contains(.,`"$BIOS`")]"

$Package = ($Packages.SelectNodes($xpathqry,$ns))
$PackageID = $Package.SelectNodes('def:S[contains(@N,"PackageID")]',$ns)
$tsenv.Value('OSDDownloadDownloadPackages') = $PackageID.InnerXML
```

and it fails on:

```bsh
$PackageID = $Package.SelectNodes('def:S[contains(@N,"PackageID")]',$ns)
```

I have tried to fudge with it for a day and I am just hitting a wall.

What I get is the following error:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XPathNodeList] doesn't contain a
method named 'SelectNodes'.
At C:\_SMSTaskSequence\Packages\NC1002CB\Get-BIOSPackages.ps1:17 char:38
+ $PackageID = $Package.SelectNodes <<<< ('def:S[contains(@N,"PackageID")]',$ns)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (SelectNodes:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is actually pretty clear. `$Packages.SelectNodes()` returns an [`XPathNodeList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnodelist) collection. In the subsequent statement you're trying to call a method `SelectNodes()` on that collection when the collection doesn't have such a method. Which is what's causing the error.

The reason why the code works in PowerShell v5 is that Microsoft introduced a new feature called ["member enumeration"](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/new-v3-language-features/) with PowerShell v3 that automagically passes calls to non-existing members (properties and methods) of a collection to the *elements* of the collection. In your case, since the collection `$Package` doesn't have a method `SelectNodes()`, calling `$Package.SelectNodes()` will throw an error in PowerShell v2 and older, and call `SelectNodes()` on the *elements* of `$package` in PowerShell v3 and newer.

There are various ways to address the issue, e.g.

- [Update PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19902239/1630171) to v3 or newer on the Windows 7 machines. Yes, I saw that you said that you can't upgrade the Windows 7 machines, but this is in fact the preferred solution.
- Restrict the result of `$Packages.SelectNodes()` to one item:

  ```
  $Package = $Packages.SelectNodes($xpathqry, $ns) |
             Select-Object -First 1
  ```
- Use onle the first element of `$Packages` in the next statment:

  ```
  $PackageID = $Package[0].SelectNodes('def:S[contains(@N,"PackageID")]',$ns)
  ```
- Call `SelectNodes()` for each element of `$Package`:

  ```
  $PackageID = $Package | ForEach-Obejct {
      $_.SelectNodes('def:S[contains(@N,"PackageID")]',$ns)
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!