# vagrant error the version of powershell on this host is less than required

Tags: powershell, windows-7, vagrant, windows-7-x64

I have a problem with vagrant.

1) I have Windows 7.

2) Run script in Windows PowerShell

3) Code that i execute:

```
PS D:\vagrants> vagrant --debug
```

4) my windows Path entry:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files\Intel\UCRT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;D:\xampp-7.2.1\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin
```

5) Last text error

```
The version of powershell currently installed on this host is less than
the required minimum version. Please upgrade the installed version of
powershell to the minimum required version and run the command again.

  Installed version: 2

  Minimum required version: 3
```

6) I runned this with debug mode

**debug information**

```
vagrant.exe :  INFO global: Vagrant version: 2.2.5
строка:1 знак:8
+ vagrant <<<<  --debug
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ( INFO global: Vagrant version: 2.2.5:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

 INFO global: Ruby version: 2.4.6
 INFO global: RubyGems version: 2.6.14.4

 INFO global: VAGRANT_EXECUTABLE="C:\\HashiCorp\\Vagrant\\embedded\\gems\\2.2.5\\gems\\vagrant-2.2.5\\bin\\vagrant"

 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_EMBEDDED_DIR="C:\\HashiCorp\\Vagrant\\embedded"
 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_ENV="1"

 INFO global: VAGRANT_INSTALLER_VERSION="2"

 INFO global: VAGRANT_LOG="debug"

 WARN global: resolv replacement has not been enabled!

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/box/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: box command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/cap/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: cap command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/cloud/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: vagrant-cloud

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/destroy/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: destroy command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/global-status/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: global-status command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/halt/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: halt command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/help/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: help command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/init/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: init command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/list-commands/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: list-commands command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/login/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: vagrant-login

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/package/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: package command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/plugin/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: plugin command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/port/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: port command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/powershell/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: powershell command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/provider/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: provider command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/provision/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: provision command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/push/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: push command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/rdp/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: rdp command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/reload/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: reload command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/resume/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: resume command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/snapshot/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: snapshot command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/ssh/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/ssh_config/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh-config command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/status/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: status command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/suspend/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: suspend command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/up/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: up command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/upload/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: upload command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/validate/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: validate command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/version/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: version command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/winrm/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: winrm command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/commands/winrm_config/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: winrm-config command

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/communicators/ssh/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ssh communicator

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/communicators/winrm/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: winrm communicator

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/communicators/winssh/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: windows ssh communicator

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/alt/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ALT Platform guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/amazon/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Amazon Linux guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/arch/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Arch guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/atomic/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Atomic Host guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/bsd/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: BSD-based guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/coreos/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: CoreOS guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/darwin/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Darwin guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/debian/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Debian guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/dragonflybsd/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: DragonFly BSD guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/elementary/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Elementary guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/esxi/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ESXi guest.

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/fedora/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Fedora guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/freebsd/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: FreeBSD guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/funtoo/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Funtoo guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/gentoo/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Gentoo guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/haiku/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Haiku guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/kali/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Kali guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/linux/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Linux guest.

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/mint/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Mint guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/netbsd/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: NetBSD guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/nixos/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: NixOS guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/omnios/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: OmniOS guest.

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/openbsd/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: OpenBSD guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/photon/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: VMware Photon guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/pld/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: PLD Linux guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/redhat/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Red Hat Enterprise Linux guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/slackware/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Slackware guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/smartos/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SmartOS guest.

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/solaris/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Solaris guest.

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/solaris11/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Solaris 11 guest.

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/suse/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SUSE guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/tinycore/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: TinyCore Linux guest.

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/trisquel/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Trisquel guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/ubuntu/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Ubuntu guest

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/guests/windows/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Windows guest.

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/hosts/alt/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ALT Platform host

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/hosts/arch/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Arch host

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/hosts/bsd/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: BSD host

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/hosts/darwin/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Mac OS X host

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/hosts/freebsd/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: FreeBSD host

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/hosts/gentoo/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Gentoo host

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/hosts/linux/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Linux host

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/hosts/null/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: null host

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/hosts/redhat/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Red Hat Enterprise Linux host

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/hosts/slackware/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Slackware host

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/hosts/suse/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SUSE host

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/hosts/void/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Void host

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/hosts/windows/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Windows host

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/kernel_v1/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: kernel

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/kernel_v2/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: kernel

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/providers/docker/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: docker-provider

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/providers/hyperv/plugin.rb
 INFO manager: Registered plugin: Hyper-V provider
DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/providers/virtualbox/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: VirtualBox provider

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/provisioners/ansible/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ansible

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/provisioners/cfengine/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: CFEngine Provisioner

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/provisioners/chef/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: chef

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/provisioners/docker/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: docker

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/provisioners/file/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: file

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/provisioners/puppet/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: puppet

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/provisioners/salt/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: salt

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/provisioners/shell/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: shell

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/pushes/atlas/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: atlas

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/pushes/ftp/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: ftp

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/pushes/heroku/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: heroku

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/pushes/local-exec/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: local-exec

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/pushes/noop/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: noop

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: NFS synced folders

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/synced_folders/rsync/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: RSync synced folders

DEBUG global: Loading core plugin: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/synced_folders/smb/plugin.rb

 INFO manager: Registered plugin: SMB synced folders

 INFO vagrant: `vagrant` invoked: ["--debug"]

DEBUG vagrant: Creating Vagrant environment

 INFO environment: Environment initialized (#<Vagrant::Environment:0x0000000004bda200>)

 INFO environment:   - cwd: D:/vagrants

 INFO environment: Home path: C:/Users/black_engel/.vagrant.d

DEBUG environment: Effective local data path: D:/vagrants/.vagrant

 INFO environment: Local data path: D:/vagrants/.vagrant

DEBUG environment: Creating: D:/vagrants/.vagrant

DEBUG manager: Enabling localized plugins

 INFO manager: Plugins:

DEBUG bundler: Current generated plugin dependency list: []

DEBUG bundler: Generating new builtin set instance.

DEBUG bundler: Generating new plugin set instance. Skip gems - []

DEBUG bundler: Activating solution set: []

 INFO manager: Loading plugins...

DEBUG manager: Enabling globalized plugins

 INFO manager: Plugins:

DEBUG bundler: Current generated plugin dependency list: []

DEBUG bundler: Generating new builtin set instance.

DEBUG bundler: Generating new plugin set instance. Skip gems - []

DEBUG bundler: Activating solution set: []

 INFO manager: Loading plugins...

 INFO loader: Set :root = ["#<Pathname:D:/vagrants/Vagrantfile>"]

DEBUG loader: Populating proc cache for #<Pathname:D:/vagrants/Vagrantfile>
DEBUG loader: Load procs for pathname: D:/vagrants/Vagrantfile

 INFO loader: Loading configuration in order: [:home, :root]

DEBUG loader: Loading from: root (evaluating)

DEBUG loader: Configuration loaded successfully, finalizing and returning

DEBUG push: finalizing

 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\/powershell.EXE", "-NoLogo", "-NoProfile", "-NonInteractive", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-Command", "Write-Output $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.Major"]

 INFO subprocess: Command not in installer, restoring original environment...

DEBUG subprocess: Selecting on IO

DEBUG subprocess: stdout: 2

DEBUG powershell: Timeout exceeded while attempting to determine version of Powershell.

ERROR vagrant: Vagrant experienced an error! Details:

ERROR vagrant: #<Vagrant::Errors::PowerShellInvalidVersion: The version of powershell currently installed on this host is less than
the required minimum version. Please upgrade the installed version of
powershell to the minimum required version and run the command again.

  Installed version: 2

  Minimum required version: 3>
ERROR vagrant: The version of powershell currently installed on this host is less than
the required minimum version. Please upgrade the installed version of
powershell to the minimum required version and run the command again.

  Installed version: 2

  Minimum required version: 3
ERROR vagrant: C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/util/powershell.rb:196:in `validate_install!'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/util/powershell.rb:96:in `execute_cmd'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:82:in `block in windows_admin?'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:84:in `windows_admin?'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/plugins/providers/hyperv/provider.rb:20:in `usable?'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:361:in `block in default_provider'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:49:in `block in each'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:48:in `each'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/registry.rb:48:in `each'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:347:in `default_provider'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:943:in `guess_provider'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:955:in `find_configured_plugins'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:983:in `process_configured_plugins'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:178:in `initialize'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/bin/vagrant:145:in `new'
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.5/gems/vagrant-2.2.5/bin/vagrant:145:in `<main>'

Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The version of powershell currently installed on this host is less than
the required minimum version. Please upgrade the installed version of
powershell to the minimum required version and run the command again.

  Installed version: 2

  Minimum required version: 3
```

Please help)))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had faced the same issue. You have to update `PowerShell` version on Windows7. You can update to PowerShell version as below:

Method1 : You can install https://chocolatey.org and run below command:

```
choco upgrade powershell
```

Method2: You can install PowerShell 4 or 5 as 'Windows update'. Powershell 4 is sufficient to rectify this issue.

Please refer this guide to upgrade to PowerShell 4 or later :
[how to upgrade powershell to later version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902239/how-to-upgrade-powershell-version-from-2-0-to-3-0%20or%20later%20version)

Comment: Thanks!!))) I am installing powershell 4, and works!!

Comment: @BlackEngel I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem even though I run...winget install Microsoft.Powershell:

Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

The version of powershell currently installed on this host is less than
the required minimum version. Please upgrade the installed version of
powershell to the minimum required version and run the command again.

Installed version: N/A
Minimum required version: 3

Comment: Me too answers are not helpful. You could instead comment on the original question or simply upvote it

Answer (score 0):

Works for me:

```
$ rm -rf .vagrant/
$ vagrant destroy -f
$ vagrant up
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered the same issue on a Windows 10 system, so I followed these steps. Also, it will resolve your problem since they are very easy to install.

Step 1: CMD opened as an administrator.

Step 2: To execute the following command on the CMD.

C:\Windows\system32> **winget install Microsoft.PowerShell**