# Vagrant cannot be started on Windows 7 64 bits requires version upgrades

Tags: vagrant

I downloaded vagrant for Windows at this link
https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads

I have just installed Vagrant on Windows 7 64 bit. When I type **vagrant up** to start it, it displays the following error below at command prompt. How do I upgrade from version 2 to 3

> C:\hhvm-vagrant>vagrant up
>
> Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:
>
> The version of powershell currently installed on this host is less than
> the required minimum version. Please upgrade the installed version of
> powershell to the minimum required version and run the command again.
>
> Installed version: 2
>
> Minimum required version: 3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vagrant error the version of powershell on this host is less than required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58122639/vagrant-error-the-version-of-powershell-on-this-host-is-less-than-required)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved by installing windows management Framework version 3.0

Answer (score 0):

If you update the powershell version to 3.0, the problem will be resolved.